# How to close activity for iOS app in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: ios, kotlin, android-activity, multiplatform

In my Kotlin Multiplatform Android/iOS app, I have a dialogue popping up when the user starts the app, asking to confirm acceptance of the conditions of use. If he declines, then the activity should close/minimise.

I use an expect/actual function construct, with

```
expect fun closeapp()
```

in the `commonMain` module.

In the Android app, I use:

```
actual fun closeapp()
{
    System.exit(-1)
}
```

to implement closing of the activity. But I don't know how to achieve the equivalent in iosMain. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Using System.exit(-1) in the actual implementation for closing the app on Android is a valid approach. It forcefully terminates the application process. However, note that using System.exit() in Android is generally not recommended unless it's a critical situation.

Here's your updated implementation:

```
// Example code to finish the activity on Android
android.app.Activity.finish()

// Example code to exit the app (not recommended in all situations)
System.exit(-1)
```

Comment: Thank you, fair point. But I’m looking for a way to close the iOS activity.